# Tensorflow strings.to_number

Tags: tensorflow

My data consists of many csv files, each csv file containing one row with many float numbers.I am trying to convert strings to float in the following

```
import tensorflow as tf

PATH = "C:\\DeepFakes\\Training\\im2data\\train\\"
#tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(False)

def process_path(file_path):

    label = tf.strings.split(file_path, "\\")[-2]
    data = tf.strings.split (tf.io.read_file(file_path),','
    try:
        data = tf.strings.to_number(
           data, out_type=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None)
    except:
        print('dddddddddddddddd')

    return data, label

file_path = PATH + "\\original\\ImA00001.csv"  
data, label = process_path(file_path)
print('data ',data, ' label ', label)
```

A sample of the data is as follows

0.00044 0.00233 0.00572 0.00190 0.13761 0.42304 0.00027 0.00286

The output is

dddddddddddddddd
data  tf.Tensor([b'0.0004401633\r\n0.0023351652\r\n0.0057266317\r\n0.0019061912\r\n0.13761024\r\n0.42304015\r\n0.0002711446\r\n0.0028613438\r\n'], shape=(1,), dtype=string)  label  tf.Tensor(b'original', shape=(), dtype=string)

Comment: can you please share the  file/partial file if possible and please display the output what you are getting...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer working code as per your instructions

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
print("Tensorflow Version:", tf.__version__)
```

You can do it this way using tf.string_split and tf.string_to_number:

```
line = tf.constant("0.00044 0.00233 0.00572 0.00190 0.13761 0.42304 0.00027 0.00286", shape=(1,))
b = tf.compat.v1.string_split(line, delimiter=" ").values
c = tf.strings.to_number(b, tf.float32)
a = np.asarray(b)

print("Given Input:",line)
print("Desired Output:",a)
```

Output:

```
Tensorflow Version: 2.1.0

Given Input: tf.Tensor([b'0.00044 0.00233 0.00572 0.00190 0.13761 0.42304 0.00027 0.00286'], shape=(1,), dtype=string)

Desired Output: [b'0.00044' b'0.00233' b'0.00572' b'0.00190' b'0.13761' b'0.42304'
 b'0.00027' b'0.00286']
```

Comment: @Thinus Potgieter- If I have answered your question, can you please accept and upvote the answer. Thank You.